# After enabling repeat date on node, calendar won't show repeated dates

Tags: datetime

I made a calendar view that displays all my events. When I created the view the content type Events wasn't enabled for repeating dates.

But now I do want repeating dates, so I enabled the repeat date modules en settings in the content type.

So when I input repeated dates it shows correctly in my node buildmodes but it doesn't show the repeats in my calendar only the first one. Can I still change the calendar to display repeated dates?

Thanks in advance

#### UPDATE

There's an issue in the date module
The last solution is for drupal 6 I think because I can't find Global Settings of 'Number of values as 1' in Drupal 7
http://drupal.org/node/1391464

## solution

I had to delete my field_event_date and recreated to be repeating
I only lost my dates instead of my full nodes.

Comment: The distinct option is off in the query settings of my view, so that shouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 1):

After deleting and recreating the date field on your content type (as in the Original post), re-add it to the list of fields in the Views context filter (Date: date(node)).

Answer (score 0):

Edit your user permission settings to allow display of repeat dates.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem but it might of prevented future problems so thanks anayway